# read clipboard into yasnippet

Tags: yasnippet

I am creating a yasnippet to create org-mode link  with content like:
`[[$1:value-read-from-clipboard][$0]]`

I wish the $1 read value from clipboard (the use-case is: I copy the URL from chrome browser and use this yasnippet to automatically attach the URL string into a link in org file).

I am using evil-mode, so the clipboard value is saved in "* register.

Question is: 
1.how to read clipboard value in yasnippet, perhaps by elisp code? 
2.I am open to any better solution to achieve this use-case.

Comment: You can also check out this [related solution](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/16425/115) which uses `org-cliplink` package.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use backticks to run elisp code in snippets. Here's a full example snippet which works for me:

```
# -*- mode: snippet; require-final-newline: nil -*-
# name: yank
# key: yank
# --
[[${1:`(current-kill 0)`}][$0]]
```

Comment: have you had chance to test this? I received error like  `[[[yas] elisp error: Wrong type argument: listp, thttps://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox][]]`

Comment: I tested it now and noticed that I forgot curly braces. I did not get an error though. I've updated the answer and also included a yasnippet header in order to get a full working example.

Comment: Sorry, but your latest code I received this `[[[yas] elisp error: Wrong type argument: listp, thttps://gitter.im/syl20bnr/spacemacs][]]` the value in clipboard is `https://gitter.im/syl20bnr/spacemacs` so the yasnippet code expands correctly but there is kinda wired error in front...

Comment: I think you should use `(current-kill 0)` instead of `(clipboard-yank)`; the backquotes tell yasnippet to insert whatever the expression returns, but `clipboard-yank` inserts the yanked string into the buffer and returns nil.

Comment: Yes @npostavs you are correct. I wonder why `clipboard-yank` worked in my Emacs though... Anyway I have edited my answer with your solution.

Comment: wow, I didnt expect there is a viable solution, but here it is! thank you both above!

Answer (score 0):

Install https://github.com/rolandwalker/simpleclip (check its README on how to install cli tools)

Then modify you snippet:

```
# -*- mode: snippet; require-final-newline: nil -*-
# name: yank
# key: yank
# --
[[${1:`(simpleclip-get-contents)`}][$0]]
```

This solution works always (Cygwin/Windows/Mac/Linux)

Answer (score 0):

This version works with fontified text and does not move the kill ring:

```
# -*- mode: snippet; require-final-newline: nil -*-
# name: yank
# key: yank
# --
[[${1:`(substring-no-properties (current-kill 0 t))`}][$0]]
```

---

Explanation:

```lisp
(substring-no-properties (current-kill 0 t))
```

- `substring-no-properties` lets you get just the raw string, e.g. just `"copied text"` instead of `#("copied text" 0 11 (fontified t face font-lock-comment-face))`
- `current_kill` has an optional argument `DO-NOT-MOVE`:

  > If optional arg `DO-NOT-MOVE` is non-nil, then don’t actually
  > move the yanking point; just return the `N`th kill forward.