# Yank during yas-expand without aborting expansion

Tags: yasnippet, yank

When expanding a yasnippet snippet and filling out completion fields yanking/pasting inserts text correctly among fields as expected, but interrupts the snippet expansion behavior (as if pressing `C-g` / calling `yas-abort-snippet`).

<strike>How can I yank content and continue with yasnippet expansion?</strike>

**Edit:**
This appears to be a problem with yasnippet itself and the order of placeholder fields.  According to the [documentation](https://capitaomorte.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html) I believe each of these forms are correct and should work.

Since this is exceptional behavior and not universally broken yanking:

**Are these forms valid / Is this in fact a bug?**

This works:

```
# -*- mode: snippet; require-final-newline: nil -*-
# name: work
# key: work_
# binding: direct-keybinding
# --
This works: ${1:someDefault}
$1
```

This doesn't:

```
# -*- mode: snippet; require-final-newline: nil -*-
# name: nowork
# key: nowork_
# binding: direct-keybinding
# --
This does not work: $1
${1:someDefault}
```

(emacs 24.5.1; yasnippet version 20160104.129)

Comment: Could you post an example snippet where this problem is occurring, and briefly walk through what happens? I can't recreate the behaviour you are describing. For me, yanking does not interrupt snippet expansion. I am even able to go to another buffer during expansion, kill some text, and then yank it into my expanding snippet in the other buffer before continuing with the expansion.

Comment: Hmm, I am on the same version of emacs and yasnippet as you, and both your examples work for me. What is not working about them for you?

Answer (score 2):

One thing that you could do (though in the example below, it would limit you to the most recent thing on the kill ring), is to use [elisp code embedded in your snippet](https://capitaomorte.github.io/yasnippet/snippet-development.html#sec-3-2):

```
# -*- mode: snippet; require-final-newline: nil -*-
# name: my-snippet
# key: foo
# binding: direct-keybinding
# --
Here is my text to yank: `(yank)`. And here is the rest: $1 $2
```

When you expand the snippet, the most recent item on your kill-ring will actually be yanked in automatically, saving you the additional step of having to yank it your self.

However, after coming up with this example, I tried yanking as normal with `C-y` during snippet expansion, and it works fine, i.e., I am able to yank, and then press `TAB` to move to the next placeholder. I am even able to cycle through the kill-ring and yank older pieces of text without interrupting snippet expansion. If you have not updated yansippet recently, you might try doing that.

Comment: It would be better to use `(current-kill 0)` instead of `(yank)`. Using `yank` modifies the buffer by side-effect which makes it dependent on the particular way in which yasnippet currently performs snippet expansion (see also http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/17044/read-clipboard-into-yasnippet)